# PHP Error from relationship field: Undefined offset: 95, Filename: relationship_parser/Tree_builder.php

Tags: templates, relationships

I have a template that is pulling in the parents of a relationship field with the {parents} tag. I'm seeing a notice when I load the page for each of the {parents}. The child's data is just a text field and not in a grid.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 95

Filename: relationship_parser/Tree_builder.php

Line Number: 544
```

This same notice is repeated for each of the parent entries. Through some research, I believe this is caused because of a malformed array being fed to Tree_builder.php, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for to fix.

I've echoed out the entry_id as they are passed into Tree_builder's function to assign entries. When I look at the database, I can see the entry_id with what appears to be valid child_id.

Any tips on debugging this would be greatly appreciated!